# How to show the loading status in mouse?

Tags: jsf, cursor, jsp-tags, wait

I create jsp page using JSF Framework.

If i perform some action(Login), then go to the backend and perform some process and it will return some value.
Here this whole process will be taken some times.

Now that time i want to show processing status (wait or busy status) in Mouse.
That means after i press Login button , i want to show that loading status in cursor...

Similarly, If i do, any action in page, then i need to show the loading status...That is, every action in my application, show the loading status.

Help me.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @eswaramoorthy-nec: Click the checkmark beside answers to some of the questions you have already asked.

Comment: @eswaramoorthy-nec, you must accept answers to your questions.  Thats how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are submitting a form you could use...

```
<form onsubmit="document.body.style.cursor='wait'"></form>
```

[Here is a list](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csscursors.shtml) of allowable cursors with CSS.
You could always set the cursor for either the page or for a component on the page via JavaScript.

Comment: Its worked. But after submit process complete, the cursor showing the wait status. i want to show the loading status during the process time only. After complete the process , the cursor go to normal view.

Comment: @eswaramoorthy-nec How are you doing your submit ? Is it just a plain html submit ? are you using Ajax ? You are going to need to reset it back in JavaScript once the submit has returned.